# Linked List Parameterized constructor

Tags: class, c++11, linked-list, queue

I tried to do a Parameterized constructor for a linked list my program is about to implement a queue by using a liked list so i want to do a parameterized constructor like Queue(int value , int size) and it dose not run or doing a list 
this is my code for this problem

```
Queue(int value,int _size)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            Node* temp = new Node;
            temp->data = value;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            if(head == nullptr)
            {
                head = tail = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                tail->next = temp;
                tail = temp;

            }
        }
    }
```

i expected that the result is to fill the lest by value times size like if i run this function Queue x(20,3) the linked list should be 
20 20 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that this is a constructor, The `head` and `tail` are not properly initialized to use them. I would suggest adding `head = tail = nullptr` just before the loop and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this code after your node creation. I hope this will work. And do use i++ instead of ++i, as the later will make the loop for size-1 times.

```
 if(head == NULL)
  head = temp;
else{
  Node *x;
  x= head;
  while(x->next != NULL)
     x = x->next;
  x->next = temp;
```

}

Comment: you will get more answers if you add tags